# Comparing two sheets

Tags: excel-formula

This is a MS Excel formula problem:

I want to compare the customer names and car model of two spreadsheets.  I can import the monthly data into a new sheet.  I want to compare Sheet1!ColumnA(customer name) and Sheet1!ColumnB(car model), with Sheet2!ColumnA(Customer name) and Sheet2!ColumnB(car model). When there's a match on both variables, return corresponding cell from Sheet2 in Column3(date).  If no match, leave blank.

I believe it's a string of logical functions, but I've tried at least twenty with no success.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sheet1:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Try:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub test()

        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        Dim LastrowS1 As Long, LastrowS2 As Long
        Dim Customer_NameS1 As String, Car_ModelS1 As String, Customer_NameS2 As String, Car_ModelS2 As String
        Dim DateS1 As Date

        LastrowS1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastrowS2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastrowS1
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                Customer_NameS1 = .Range("A" & i).Value
                Car_ModelS1 = .Range("B" & i).Value
                DateS1 = .Range("C" & i).Value
            End With
                For j = 2 To LastrowS2
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
                        Customer_NameS2 = .Range("A" & j).Value
                        Car_ModelS2 = .Range("B" & j).Value
                    End With

                    If Customer_NameS1 = Customer_NameS2 And Car_ModelS1 = Car_ModelS2 Then
                        Sheet2.Range("C" & j).Value = DateS1
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next j

            Next i

    End Sub
```